# Get "VP" and "NP" tags from Stanford Parser in c#

Tags: c#, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford Parser library for c#. In the code below I want to identify words which has "NP" tag in parsed tree but I couldn't find any function to do that. anyone can help me?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var jarRoot = @"..\..\..\..\paket-files\nlp.stanford.edu\stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09\models\";
        var modelsDirectory = jarRoot + @"\edu\stanford\nlp\models";

        // Loading english PCFG parser from file
        var lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(@"..\englishPCFG.ser.gz");

        // This option shows parsing a list of correctly tokenized words
        var sent = new[] { "This", "is", "an", "easy", "sentence", "." };
        var rawWords = Sentence.toCoreLabelList(sent);
        var parse = lp.apply(rawWords);
       // parse.pennPrint();

        // This option shows loading and using an explicit tokenizer
        const string Sent2 = "This is a test sentence.";
        var tokenizerFactory = PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "");
        var sent2Reader = new StringReader(Sent2);
        var rawWords2 = tokenizerFactory.getTokenizer(sent2Reader).tokenize();
        parse = lp.apply(rawWords2);

        var tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
        var gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
        var gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
        var tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();
        //System.Console.WriteLine("\n{0}\n", tdl);



        var tp = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");
        tp.printTree(parse);
            string s = "";
    }
```